# Is it possible for CSS to escape the shadow dom (Polymer)?

Tags: javascript, css, polymer, web-component

I have a drop-down element in Polymer.  Because of z-indexing issues, I need to pull the drop-down part out and make it a direct child of `<body>`.  Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to do that and still be able to actually style the element.  The only solution I can come up with is to make the drop-down portion its own polymer tag, but that seems really... backwards.

In short, I have an element:

```
<my-element>
    <template>
        <style>...</style>

        <input>
        <div id="dropdown">...</div>
    </template>
</my-element>
```

And then JS in the element that does `document.body.appendChild( this.$.dropdown )`

I'm trying to figure out how to stylize the drop-down once its been moved, but Polymer/Web Components' CSS isolation is preventing me from doing that.

Comment: no you don't. You don't take things out of the shadow DOM to solve a z-indexing problem: a custom element is not like HTML on your page, it's the protected content inside a single, atomic element. Can you forget about your solution, and instead describe what the problem is you are facing?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans -- Yes, I do. While I appreciate your opinion and potential help with the issue, please don't treat people like their answer is immediately wrong without knowing details. The problem is very simple -- I have a "select box" where the drop-down is getting hidden in some cases because the parent nodes either have overflow: hidden or they simply have a stacking context set. As my drop-down needs to go on top of _everything on the page_, the solution is to pull it out of the node's shadow DOM in one way or the other.

Comment: I can only answer based on the details you gave. If your regular page content is hiding the dropdown from the custom element, the only correct solution is to make your page not do that overflow hiding: a custom element is meant to be fully locked off from the rest of the world, and it can only take up as much room as your page's CSS allows it. Taking elements out means you're treating it as if it's an HTML template instance rather than a custom element. If you're going with custom elements, that choice gives up the luxury of "taking things out" (even though you *can* write hacks that do that)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans -- That's not at all true.  Custom elements are meant to be contained, but the very nature of certain things (select-boxes, global popups/overlays, drag-drops, etc), combined with the restrictive nature of certain aspects of HTML, _require_ modification of the global DOM to accomplish certain tasks. The elements are still logically isolated, but their display isn't always. In addition, certain elements like _core-drag-drop_ do the same thing and append to `document.body`. You're basically saying "never write a select box as a web-component". Nobody would agree with that.

Comment: that's putting words under my fingers. I'm going on information from talks with the Polymer devs, so that's all I can give you. The hack is as simple as any other JS (just access the shadow dom for the element, it's not really hard to find) but a problem caused by CSS is principally a problem solvable with CSS. In this case, it sounds like a job for [/deep/](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/styling.html#sdcss) to ensure the correct higher z-index

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans -- Is it?  How else do you propose writing a select box?  Requiring that the surrounding UI be aware of the web-component internals breaks isolation significantly more than what I'm proposing. The JS side of things is a simple hack, yes, but the question wasn't about that, it was about the CSS side of things, specifically if it's possible to pull CSS out of the Shadow DOM (without doing it via JS, which requires modifying/moving all the rules). I honestly don't want to have an internet-fight here :) If you have a valid solution, I'd love to hear it, but "don't" isn't one.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans -- Further, polymer significantly pollutes all of their layout CSS (`horizontal layout`, etc...)

Comment: wait, I may be misreading the question, but that's not actually what you're asking about in your post? I just reread it, and it doesn't seem to match what your last comment said you wanted to know. Feel free to ignore anything I've said so far, but the original question might need a rephrasing then, and maybe a jsbin example to show the problem you're facing so others can adjust it and post a solution bin.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans -- eh, I'm writing a custom element to promote any of the parent element's CSS selectors that start with `body` right now :)

Comment: There's also the `:host-context(queryselector)` notation for elements that need to force styling in the owning document/fragment, might be less work

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans -- But that doesn't apply once I move the element to body

Comment: true. Although I'm also curious if simply setting the dropdown's containing element to `position:relative` and then setting the dropdown itself to `position: absolute; top:0; left:0; z-index:999999999` (which due to the owner's relative would keep it fixed in place) would fix things. Without a jsbin, hard to test.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans -- elements _can't_ escape stacking context.  The moment I have something with `position:relative;z-index:1;`, and another similar element next to it, the drop-down can never go over the following element.  Similar issue with `overflow: hidden`.  I really don't want the app to have to be aware of the internals of the drop-down.

Comment: fair enough. I did just try http://jsbin.com/zubiqonuyule/1/edit though, and that seems to work. but that could be a polymer quirk.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans -- select boxes don't take up space, so you'd need to absolutely position your node to see what I mean.  Anyway, I created an element that is solely responsible for pulling out CSS, see my answer.

Comment: that's a neat element.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans -- Thanks :)  I've been creating a number of such elements, like one that allows me to override internal templates with external ones.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans -- damn it.  Polymer can't route events when I do this... gah!  Okay, looks like I'm going to have to make the drop-down piece its own element

Answer (score 1):

[edit] Note that polymer can't properly handle `on-*` event handlers attached via the DOM with this method due to the fact that it can't walk the DOM tree back up to the polymer-element.  So events need to be manually attached to anything using this.

I created a custom element that can be inserted into any element and it will pull out all rules that start with `body` and promote them to a new stylesheet inserted into `head`.  There is a bit of work to be done, specifically around browsers that need to be polyfilled as the `::shadow` selector won't work.  But I'll get to that shortly.

```
<link rel="import" href="../polymer/polymer.html" />
<polymer-element name="promote-body-css">
    <script>
        'use strict';

        ~function(){
            var promoted = {};

            function promote( node ){
                var nodeName = node.nodeName;

                if( promoted[ nodeName ] ){ return; }

                var promoteRules = [];

                [].forEach.call( node.querySelectorAll( '::shadow style' ), function( stylesheet ){
                    [].forEach.call( stylesheet.sheet.cssRules, function( rule ){
                        if( rule.cssText.indexOf( 'body ' ) === 0 ){
                            promoteRules.push( rule.cssText );
                        }
                    } );
                } );

                if( promoteRules.length ){
                    var stylesheet = document.createElement( 'style' );
                    stylesheet.innerHTML = promoteRules.join( '' ) + '/* Inserted from polymer element ' + nodeName + ' */';

                    document.getElementsByTagName( 'head' )[0].appendChild( stylesheet );
                }
            }

            promoted[ nodeName ] = 1;

            Polymer( 'promote-body-css', {
                attached : function( parent ){
                    promote( ( parent = this.parentNode ).host || parent );
                }
            } );
        }();
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```